# Using 'this' to select attribute and then compare against the selected HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to select some HTML content and then use the HTML content to compare against an array element.

This is the code that I am using.

```
 $('.foo').each(function (i) {
        $(this).click(function () {
            for (i in Data) {
                foo = JSON.parse(Data[i]);

                for (f in foo) {

                    if (foo[f].Title == **???**) {

                        $('.vert-text').html('<h1>' + foo[f].Title + '</h1>');

                        $('#topRow').html('<h3>' + foo[f].Content + '<h3>');
                    }
                };
            };
        });
    });
```

How do I use the HTML text that is selected on click to compare against `foo[f].Title`?

I am able to compare against a string and that works for one scenario but it obviously doesn't scale or work for any of the other options.

**Edit**
 The markup that I am trying to select is in the following format:

```
<ul>
    <li>Heading1</li>
    <li>Heading2</li>
    <li>Heading3</li>
    <li>Heading4</li>
</ul>
```

On the heading is selected and matched to the title in the object and then the corresponding information is displayed.

Any ideas would be great.

Cheers.

Comment: pls post your mark up also

Comment: How do you get `text that is selected on click`? Is that selected by the user, or the content of the element that was clicked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want html contents:

```
if (foo[f].Title == $(this).html()) {
```

If you want only text contents:

```
if (foo[f].Title == $(this).text()) {
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your reply. Like I said above this selects all of the items in the list. How do I do only select the individual item that I clicked on?

Comment: so `foo` is the class given to the `<li>` elements and your click function is being bound to each one of them to select its text and compare to the `Title`. Is this correct?

Comment: Argh dam! Of course, I'm selecting the whole `<ul>` no wonder it is selecting all of them. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(this).text()`(you might have to trim it) like

```
if (foo[f].Title == $.trim($(this).text())) {
}
```

also there is no need to use .each()

```
//click handler for all elements
$('.foo').click(function () {
    for (i in Data) {
        foo = JSON.parse(Data[i]);

        for (f in foo) {

            if (foo[f].Title == $.trim($(this).text())) {

                $('.vert-text').html('<h1>' + foo[f].Title + '</h1>');

                $('#topRow').html('<h3>' + foo[f].Content + '<h3>');
            }
        };
    };
});
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your reply. This selects all of the items in the list. How do I do only select the individual item that I clicked on?